# Neo4j Blueprints vs Native Traversal Speed . .

Tags: performance, testing, neo4j

I am doing a performance test of neo4j's traversal speed between neo4j's blueprints and native implementation. I have created a graph of 1000 nodes with 1 node per level i.e.

O->O->O->O->. . . .->O

I have recorded an iteration (for loop code) time of 90ms, 93ms and 79ms (ran 3 times) using this blueprints code:

```
Iterable<Vertex> vertices = testGraph.getVertices();

//Code block which was measured.
for(Vertex vertex : vertices){};
```

and using native code 270ms, 268ms and 321ms:

```
Iterable<Node> nodes = Traversal.description().breadthFirst().relationships(CustomRelTypes.LINKED_TO, Direction.OUTGOING).evaluator(Evaluators.all()).traverse(rootNode).nodes();

//Code block which was measured.
for(Node node : nodes){}
```

I cant understand how is neo4j's blueprints implementation is faster. I havent done any special configuration for any one of them. Time is almost same for depthFirst too.

does anyone how i can speed up native performance to match blueprints'.

thank you.

Comment: well, the Blueprints implementation goes against the core Neo4j API, which also the traversal API is built upon. From that perspective it should be faster, but not that much. Got that testcase around somewhere?

Comment: Are the same things compared here ? testGraph.getVertices() is comparable to graphDb.getAllNodes() instead of this traversal (relationships are used, not when looking for nodes), isn't it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blueprints uses Neo4j's native getAllNodes() methods under the hood, not the traversal API:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/master/blueprints-neo4j-graph/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/impls/neo4j/Neo4jGraph.java#L339

So the equivalent native Neo4j Java code would be:

```
g = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase('/path/to/graph-dir');
g.getAllNodes();
```